# Replacing a String between 2 pipes c#

Tags: c#, replace, pipe

I have a problem in C# to replace a string between two pipes or with an ending pipe.

Example: I want to replace the second value

Before: 0|**1**|2|3

After Replace: 0|**4**|2|3

How can I do this? The value can be also 2 digits or more.

And a second question: how can i replace the first value where is no beginning pipe?

It should be dynamicly to select which value I would like to change like "replaceString(string text, int valueindexToReplace, string replacewiht)"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: use string.split and string.join?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 4):

This example lets you replace the second number ( index = 1 ) with "4".

```
string s = "0|1|2|3";
var split = s.Split( '|' );
split[1] = "4";
string after = string.Join( "|", split );
```

Or with the method as you suggested:

```
string s = "0|1|2|3";
string after = replaceString( s, 1, "4" );

string replaceString(string text, int valueindexToReplace, string replaceWith)
{
    var split = text.Split('|');
    split[valueindexToReplace] = replaceWith;
    string after = string.Join("|", split);
    return after;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public string SetInPipe(string pipe, int index, string pipeItem)
{
     var split = pipe.Split('|');
     split[index] = pipeItem;
     return string.Join("|", split);
}
```

Example:

```
var result = SetInPipe("0|1|2|3", 1, "4");
```